# fix an element to the right and reduce it's width in left -> right direction

Tags: javascript, html, css

I will let the code speak for itself.

I want to be able to have two images/logos, which are different in color super-imposed upon one other, and being able to adjust the width of one of the images so that the logo appears to be changing colors. I have something that works, just that it works in the right to left direction. I want it left to right.

Here's my code (http://jsfiddle.net/Ym7Ex/1/),

```
<div id="outer">
<span id="img_black"></span>
<span id="img_blue"></span>
</div>

#img_black {
    width : 800px;
    height : 250px;
    position : absolute;
    float : left;
    background-color : black;
}


#img_blue {
    width : 800px;
    height : 250px;
    position : absolute;
    float : right;
    background-image : url('http://d1fzn3ba6zmp2v.cloudfront.net/images/go%20green%20(800x250).jpg');
}


#outer {
width : 800px;
height : 250px;
}


var curr_width = 800;

function setWidth() {
    document.getElementById("img_blue").style.width = (curr_width + 'px').toString();
    console.log("width" + curr_width);
    curr_width--;
    if (curr_width > 0) {
        setTimeout(setWidth, 10)
    }
}

setWidth();
```

just to demonstrate i have used a picture and a color fill, the color fills in from right to left. I need it from left to right, while keeping the picture static (it doesn't shift)

this one does it from left to right, but the picture shifts. I want to be able to keep the picture static.
http://jsfiddle.net/Ym7Ex/2/

Help appreciated.

Comment: Are you looking for something like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/Ym7Ex/3/)? I have just tweaked the JS.

Comment: Let me clarify: you want the image to fade in instead of push around?The question is a little difficult to understand

Comment: @Harry, yes I did. embarrassed!! I need some sleep. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The current code was adjusting the width from 800 to 0 pixels. Instead change it to do like 0 to 800 pixels like below.

```
var curr_width = 0; //modified this

function setWidth() {
    document.getElementById("img_blue").style.width = (curr_width + 'px').toString();
    console.log("width" + curr_width);
    curr_width++; // and this
    if (curr_width < 800) { //and this.
        setTimeout(setWidth, 10)
    }
}

setWidth();
```

[**Demo Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/V8Gaj/)